# Values of Array are changed even though not passed a reference C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

So in the below code it's a simple script to generate the faces of a cube, I'm curious (and can only find C++ examples here) why the int[] triangles inside of CreateTriangles is able to be assigned to from inside of SetQuad even though I didn't pass it as a reference. I'm very new to C# so forgive me if this is a stupid question but from what I read on MSDN regarding refs there's something I clearly don't understand. 
I would have thought to get this effect you'd need to use "ref int[] ..."

```
 private static int SetQuad (int[] triangles, int i, int v00, int v10, int v01, int v11){
            triangles [i] = v00;
            triangles [i + 1] = triangles [i + 4] = v01;
            triangles [i + 2] = triangles [i + 3] = v10;
            triangles [i + 5] = v11;
            return i + 6;
        }

    private void CreateTriangles () {
        int quads = (xSize * ySize + xSize * zSize + ySize * zSize) * 2;
        int[] triangles = new int[quads * 6];
        int ring = (xSize + zSize) * 2;
        int t = 0, v = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++, v++) {
            for (int q = 0; q < ring - 1; q++, v++) {
                t = SetQuad (triangles, t, v, v + 1, v + ring, v + ring + 1);
            }
            t = SetQuad (triangles, t, v, v - ring + 1, v + ring, v + 1);
        }
        t = CreateTopFace (triangles, t, ring);
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass by `ref` if you want to assign the `triangles` variable to some other array *and have that assignment propagate to the caller*.

That's what `ref` does, it allows assignment to propagate. Because `Array<int>` is a reference type, you are already passing a reference around (*by value*) and so modifications to the object's state are automatically "picked up" by the caller, since they are both pointing to the same object.